# In a non-compact metric space, topological transitivity need not imply onto

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems

I had asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2601034/in-a-non-compact-metric-space-topologically-transitivity-need-not-imply-onto) question on [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) yesterday but it got no response so I'm asking here.

---

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $f:X \to X$ be continuous. If $f$ is topologically transitive. Then $f$ is onto.

> I'm trying to show that the compactness hypothesis cannot be removed.
>
> I couldn't find any example of a non-compact metric space and a continuous function which is topologically transitive but not onto.

Any hints will be appreciated.

**Note:** If $(X,f)$ is a dynamical system. Then $f$ is said to be topologically transitive if for every pair of non-empty open sets $U$ and $V$ in $X$ there exists $n \geq 1$ such that $f^n(U) \cap V\neq \emptyset.$

Comment: It's now answered on MathSE.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By [Birkhoff's theorem](http://home.iitk.ac.in/~chavan/linear_dynamics.pdf), a bounded linear operator on a Banach space is topologically transitive if and only if it is [hypercyclic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercyclic_operator). Charles Read has developed a whole machinery for constructing non-surjective, hypercyclic operators on spaces of the form $\ell_1(X)$:

> C.J. Read, [The invariant subspace problem for a class of Banach spaces, II. Hypercyclic operators](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02765019). *Israel J. Math.*, **63** (1) (1988), 1-40.

Of course, possibly these are not the easiest counter-examples for your purposes, although I find them quite instructive.

Comment: Your counter-example, while is interesrting, lacks compactness.

Comment: @Leandro this was precisely the question, since there's no compact counterexample

Comment: You right @Ycor.

Comment: @TomekKania That's a very interesting example. Thank you.